# Double.parseDouble - any strict implementation for same results on diff platforms?

Tags: java

I need some floating point operations to produce the same exact results between different machines. I see we have things like strictfp and StrictMath to do this. My starting state however will load the floating point numbers from a String. Example:

```
double x = Double.parseDouble("0.1234..");
```

I don't see something like StrictMath.parseDouble() though. Is there something like that?

My app has to save the state of the operations to disk at arbitrary points and reload state, I'm not even sure parseDouble will restore values to their exact representations on the same machine.

I believe I might have to use a fixed point math approach for this, but wanted to check if I'm missing anything here.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to restore the original state, why don't you just store the String?

Comment: @SJuan76 yes I am, I'm wondering if when you parse the String will the double be exactly the same representation to ensure future operations don't drift.

Comment: Ok, you mean you will be doing double -> String -> double and wonder if that conversion will change the value, right?

Comment: @SJuan76 yeah exactly

Comment: @SJuan76 In that case there's no such guarantee, try this for example: `System.out.println( Double.parseDouble("0.1234567890123456789012345678901234567890"));`

Comment: Ok, yeah I was not aware of StrictMath.java or strictfp until recently, was wondering if there was anything similar for trying to parse a double in this manner for this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I need some floating point operations to produce the same exact results between different machines.

This is what Double.parseDouble does.  From the Javadoc from Double.valueOf

> Returns a Double object holding the double value represented by the argument string s.

Comment: Right but is there any way to ensure that the parsed double is strictly the same on all machines/platforms. If diff instances are slightly different, then the operations will start to drift and I'll end up with slightly different results.

Comment: @user1219278 I can't see any such guarantee in the documentation but a quick glance at the [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java#FloatingDecimal.doubleValue%28%29) seems to suggest that the authors have gone quite a long way to ensure you get the same result anywhere.